# Are there "Type-unsafe" function parameters in c# and how could we make one?

Tags: c#, function

```
public List<string> Attributes = new List<string>();

public void Add(string key, string value)
{
    if (value.ToString() != "")
    {
        Attributes.Add(key + "=\"" + value + "\" ");
    }
}

public void Add(string key, int value)
{
    if (value.ToString() != "")
    {
        Attributes.Add(key + "=\"" + value + "\" ");
    }
}
```

So, instead of having two Add functions, could we make just one? For example

```
public void Add(string key, <var> value)
{
    if (value.ToString() != "")
    {
        Attributes.Add(key + "=\"" + value + "\" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain what exactly is what you want to accomplish? :-)

Comment: since both functions have exactly the same contents, i figured why not just have a single function that will be used for two types... =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that in this case, the integer version of your function has to be converted to a string anyway for inclusion in the list.  So if your entire problem is really as stated, you only need the string version of your function and can call it like this:

```
int SomeValue = 42;
string SomeName= "The Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything";
Add(SomeName, SomeValue.ToString());
```

But if you are asking about a more general problem, you can just use the `object` type, like this:

```
public void Add(string key, object value)
{
    if (value.ToString() is {Length: >0})
    {
        Attributes.Add($"{key}=\"{value}\" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void Add<T>(string key, T value)
{
    if (value.ToString() != "")
    {
        Attributes.Add(key + "=\"" + value + "\" ");
    }
}
```

usage

```
Add("key", 22);
Add("key", "value");
```

Comment: Much, much better than type-unsafe methods.

ps. The Add's can be used without type following them, as the type is inferred by the compiler from the value being passed in.  eg.  Add("key", 1) and Add("key", "value")

Comment: There's no reason for a generic in this case.  If you don't like object, pretend it's some magic "IStringable" interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

use Object for the type.

```
public void Add(string key, object value)
{
     if(value == null) {return;}

     var sval = value.ToString();
     if(sval != "")
     { Attributes.Add( key + "=\"" + sval + "\""}
}
```